# Matching <If>/<Else> conditionals for specific URIs doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

I need to create a conditional to avoid back-office url/files to be cached.

All these patterns need to be skipped:

- .com/panel
- .com/panel/
- .com/panel/something
- .com/api
- .com/api/
- .com/api/something

Can't make this work. I tried many versions and this is my last one:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(panel|api)#">
  ExpiresActive Off
</If>
<Else>
  ExpiresActive On
  ...
</Else>
```

Comment: Do you have [Apache 2.4](https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4)?

Comment: @Martin yes (2.4.39 to be more precise). This work `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /panel/">` but skipped /panel

Comment: Try : `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#(panel|api).*#">
  ExpiresActive Off
</If>`

Comment: Still got an expiration date (so its cached) on requests like `.com/panel/login` and `.com/api/system?view=panel` (expires: Fri, 24 May 2019 18:28:21 GMT) on a newly private tab but not on `.com/media/panel/.../file.js`